# Linker is unable to open COMCTRLS.OBJ

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I'm just trying to rebuild my `C++` Builder project from `RAD Studio XE` to `XE5`.
As this is a rather big project I'm already struggling since a week (updating / modifying several Delphi components etc.) to do so.

What I finally could not fix is the linker error telling me `COMCTRLS.OBJ` can't be opened. As I have seen the recommendation to make a new project file instead of upgrading in an answer to a similar question I did so (this costed me another half day), but nothing has been changed.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Presumably we can reproduce this?

Comment: have you done a search on your HD for COMCRTLS.OBJ and then ensured your project paths point to its location?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - please see at https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=648072#648072

> > Make sure you don't have any old .obj/.dcu/.lib files being carried
> >     over from an earlier XE compilation to your XE5 environment.
> >     Double-check your Project and IDE search paths to make sure old XE
> >     paths are not being referenced by XE5.
>
> I definitely had an old LIB file from a Delphi package created by XE
>   which was referenced by accident instead of the new LIB already
>   created by XE5 although I've installed XE5 on a completely different
>   PC where no Embarcadero was on before (working with two versions on
>   the same PC is more or less completely impossible - you always will
>   have conflicts).